# Scala: Type Inference Failure on Lambda of Generic Numeric Type

Tags: scala, generics, type-inference

In Scala 2.13.10, I'm running across this problem:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

class Test[T : Numeric : ClassTag](data: Seq[T]) {

  def map(fn: T => T): Test[T] = { new Test(this.data.map(fn)) }

  def +(y: T): Test[T] = {
    this.map(x => x + y)
  }

}
```

does not compile. The error is

```
[Error] Test.scala:10:23: type mismatch;
 found   : T
 required: String
```

Removing the "+" method to make it compile and using the `Test.map` method with e.g. `t.map(x => x + y)` works fine. I suspect the type inference algorithm needs a little more to go with to infer that these values are numeric and that the "+" operator in the lambda therefore isn't the string concatenation. How can I achieve that?

FWIW, IntelliJ flags the general area of the problem in the editor but with a different, weird error message. Not going to go into that as it is probably unrelated.

Comment: You are not importing the `Numeric` syntax. Actually, not even sure how the `*` worked then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should import the `infixNumericOps` to make the operator works for Numeric:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

class Test[T : Numeric : ClassTag](data: Seq[T]) {

  def map(fn: T => T): Test[T] = { new Test(this.data.map(fn)) }

  def +(y: T): Test[T] = {
    import math.Numeric.Implicits.infixNumericOps
    this.map(x => x + y)
  }

}
```